# ¿Cómo puedo traer más datos a la vista?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Estoy aprendiendo a usar .Net solo que tengo una duda, ¿Cómo traigo mas atributos de una tabla?

Por ejemplo, de la tabla grupo muestro el grupo pero con tiene relación con la tabla alumno traigo al alumno, en la alumno tengo otros atributos que quiero mostrar pero no sé cómo traerlos, estuve investigando que usaban LINQ que es equivalente a JOIN pero no me quedo la implementación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Controlador Grupo

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
```

{
    public class grupoController : Controller
    {
        private exampleEntities1 db = new exampleEntities1();

```
    // GET: grupo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var grupo = db.grupo.Include(g => g.alumno);
        return View(grupo.ToList());
    }

    // GET: grupo/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: grupo/Create
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_grupo,nom_grupo,id_alumno")] grupo grupo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.grupo.Add(grupo);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // POST: grupo/Edit/5
    // Para protegerse de ataques de publicación excesiva, habilite las propiedades específicas a las que desea enlazarse. Para obtener 
    // más información vea https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id_grupo,nom_grupo,id_alumno")] grupo grupo)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(grupo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.id_alumno = new SelectList(db.alumno, "id_alumno", "nom", grupo.id_alumno);
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // GET: grupo/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        if (grupo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(grupo);
    }

    // POST: grupo/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        grupo grupo = db.grupo.Find(id);
        db.grupo.Remove(grupo);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: vas a tener que mostrar que estas haciendo, estructuras de las tablas ,codigo.. no sabemos que estas trayendo ni como, entonces no podemos decirte como traer mas...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner tu código?

Comment: claro que si ya moste el codigo

Answer (score 1):

Imagino estas usando Entity Framework (EF)

La clave esta en tu linea de código

```
var grupo = db.grupo.Include(g => g.alumno);
```

Con esta, básicamente, estas diciendo que también se incluyan los alumnos pertenecientes al grupo. Un 'inner join', al final del día.

Hasta aquí, lo tienes bien. Lo que necesitas hacer ahora es usaron en tu vista. Y como no muestras el código de la vista, pondré algo genérico para que te des una idea de como se usa en la vista.

```
@model List<WebApplication2.Models.Grupo>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var grupo in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @foreach (var alumno in grupo.Alumnos)
                {
                    <span>@alumno.Nombre</span>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

O hacer llamado a uno en especifico:

```
<span>@Model.FirstOrDefault().Alumnos.FirstOrDefault().Nombre</span>
```

etc..

Comment: Hola Jorge, algo parecido ya lo tengo en la vista y me muestran los campos correctamente, solo que quiero empesar a usar LINQ para entenderle pero no me queda. ¿Quieres que deje mi codigo de la vista?

Comment: Creo que sería de más ayuda nos extendieras la pregunta con mayor detalle de lo que necesitas. Por supuesto ver el código de la vista nos ayuda también.. Saludos..

Comment: Claro, ya mostre mi publicacion